# Issue with fixed header and slidetoggle

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css-position, navigationbar

I have a static Bootstrap menu that has a jQuery slideToggle area above it which is activated using a link alongside the menu.

The issue i have is that the when the toggle is open, the menu remains static on the screen but the toggle area is moving with the content.

My HTML is

```
<div class="dropdownwrap"></div>
<header id="mpthis" class="banner navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="banner">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="toplogo"> <a id="dropdown" href="#" title="Click This Button">X</a>
            </div>
            <nav class="nav-main nav-collapse collapse" role="navigation">
                <ul id="menu-primary-navigation" class="nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 7</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<div id="content">
    <p>Croissant chocolate muffin. Powder fruitcake fruitcake cupcake fruitcake sesame snaps. Fruitcake macaroon sesame snaps candy cake bear claw tart tiramisu. Sugar plum wafer pie ice cream marshmallow bear claw powder. Sesame snaps cotton candy jelly beans ice cream. Muffin gummies jelly beans croissant tootsie roll cake marshmallow dragée. Jelly-o cookie toffee oat cake. Chupa chups dessert fruitcake gummies fruitcake muffin gummi bears ice cream. Bonbon pudding cake soufflé macaroon sweet roll. Oat cake jelly-o pastry. Sweet roll cotton candy chupa chups cheesecake. Unerdwear.com chocolate candy canes gummi bears tootsie roll apple pie toffee pastry.</p><div>
```

My CSS is

```
.dropdownwrap {background-color:#ef0403;display:none;height: 150px;width: 100%;z-index: 1000;top: 0;position: relative;}.navbar {width: 100%;height: 44px;background: #eee;display: block;}#toplogo {float: left;}.navbar .nav>li {float: left;list-style: none;padding: 0px 14px;}.navbar-fixed-top {position: fixed;right: 0;left: 0;z-index: 1030;margin-bottom: 0;}.navbar-fixed-mp {right: 0;left: 0;z-index: 1030;position: fixed;}#content {padding-top: 34px}
```

My jQuery is

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
jQuery(".dropdownwrap").hide();
jQuery('#dropdown').click(function () {

    if (!jQuery(".dropdownwrap").is(":visible")) jQuery('#mpthis').removeClass("navbar-fixed-top").addClass("navbar-fixed-mp");
    jQuery('.wrap').addClass("fixthis");


    jQuery(".dropdownwrap").slideToggle(function () {
        if (!jQuery(".dropdownwrap").is(":visible")) jQuery('#mpthis').addClass("navbar-fixed-top").removeClass("navbar-fixed-mp");
        jQuery('.wrap').removeClass("fixthis");



    });
});
```

});

I have created a fiddle which is below, this demonstrates what is happening

http://jsfiddle.net/blayney/XDUuX/24/

If anyone can help it would be appreciated

Thanks

Matt

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you got your answer, but the problem was that you were removing `navbar-fixed-top`, which has the `position: fixed` attribute, and replacing it with `navbar-fixed-mp`, also fixed. The `fixed` position means that the element is positioned in relation to the browser, not the page-- hence why it doesn't scroll. If you just remove `navbar-fixed-top` and don't replace it with `navbar-fixed-mp`, you should get the desired effect.

http://jsfiddle.net/XDUuX/28/